# Undefined yet defined variable?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

Here I define a variable:
`var number = Math.round(Math.random() * 10);`
When I plug it into the Chrome DevTools JavaScript Console, I get a very weird error:  `undefined`.  I have never seen this error before, and I don't see how the variable is undefined.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

(I'm sure this is one of those in-plain-sight issues.)

Comment: *"Is there something I'm doing wrong?"* Nope, that's normal output in the console, since the `var` statement doesn't return anything. It's certainly not an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's right. This expression returns `undefined` - because `var` doesn't return anything.

But if you type `number` and press enter you will get the result.